# Is there a way to check if a field (not doc) is modified in the pre save method?

Tags: mongoose

Do you know if there is a way to check if a field (not doc) is modified in the pre save method using mongoose ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of late to party, but maybe still helpful: [`this.isModified('fieldName')`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified)